# Firefox add-on to sync only a single bookmarks folder

Tags: firefox, file-synchronization, bookmark

There seem to be a few options for syncing Firefox bookmarks, such as [Firefox Sync](https://account.services.mozilla.com/) and [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/). **Are there any other services which might allow the user to sync only a single bookmark folder between computers?** I would like this situation:

```
// Home computer bookmarks

+ Animals
  How to pet a rat
  How to feed a snake

+ Film
  The Opry House

+ Shared
  StackoverFlow
  SuperUser


// Work computer bookmarks

+ Python
  PEP8 reference
  GIL reference

+ Shared
  StackoverFlow
  SuperUser
```

Firefox Sync has the limitation that one must sync **all** their bookmarks, i.e. the entire bookmarks feature will be identical on all synced computers. Thus, I cannot leave the `Animals` folder only at home and the `Python` folder only at work.

Xmarks has the limitation that all folders must be uploaded to the server. Thus, the server will have the `Animals`, `Python`, and `Shared` folders and I can select which folders to download to which computer. This would not be a problem if I had a reasonable amount of bookmarks. However, I happen to have about 40,000 bookmarks at home and syncing them is beyond all reason. No, I cannot purge them: they are there for a reason!

**Does there exist a Firefox add-on that will let the user select only certain folders for syncing?**

There exist many bookmarks on the home computer that I don't want to sync to an external server. For purpose of discussion, let's assume some material which is legal where I reside but not legal where Xmarks servers are (such as links to download [The Opry House](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Opry_House) which is out of copyright in most of the world, but still protected IP in the US).

*Note that this question was originally asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/790210/sync-only-a-single-bookmarks-folder) but it was (rightly) closed there as off-topic as it is asking for a software (add-on) suggestion.*

Comment: I didn't know that XMarks allows you to select folders to sync TO your computer. You probably didn't know that you don't have to use *their* server, but can use your own service (I do that e.g. via FTP with my "NAS"). And we both don't know whether the two can be combined. I could check that when back at home, if you can tell me where to look for it: when I looked the last time, I didn't see a corresponding option – so it might well be restricted to their service (which I never used).

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same boat. I'm posting here to keep track of any updates.

A short term fix I've done is using the manual export bookmarks to HTML from the first computer, editing that HTML to only include the folder I want to sync, then importing to the second computer.

It not be a terrible process as long as you can find your "shared" folder in the tree. Just delete the siblings to that folder.

[image: "Interesting" is a folder, its children are the links in the folder.]

Comment: For the OP's 40000 bookmarks that is not a very workable solution

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. Though this might work for some users so it is good that you mention it, like Jan stated this won't be feasible on my system. Maybe I'll automate it with Python, though! +1

Comment: Isn't this going to create duplicates?